# Template class hierarchy friend inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, protected

I'm tinkering with C++ and are facing the following problem:

Given:

```
class A {
    int aVar;

public:
    A(){}
    virtual ~A(){};
};

template<class BASE>
class B: public BASE {
    int bVar;

public:
    B() : BASE() {}
    virtual ~B() {}
};

template<class BASE>
class C: public BASE{
    int cVar;

public:
    C() : BASE() {}
    virtual ~C() {}
}

D,E,F,G...
```

I can do a sort of branched class hierarchy that inherits parameters and functions and such. Like `typedef C<B<A>> ABC;`

However, I am supposed to have class as well that "manages" certain combinations of these objects through protected access.

```
template<class TYPE>
struct Manager {
    TYPE current;

    Manager() {
        current.aVar++;
        current.bVar++;
        current.cVar++;    
    }
    ~Manager(){}
};
```

And my question is: How do I set up the `A`, `B`, and `C` classes to friend Manager regardless of `Manager`'s template type? (e.g. `Manager` with template `ABC`, `EABC`, `DABC`, `XYZEFGABC`, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have them friend any manager:

```
class A {
    template <typename T>
    friend struct Manager;
};

template<class BASE>
class B: public BASE {
    template <typename T>
    friend struct Manager;
};

// etc.
```

Comment: @dyp Were there more fixes than changing `class` to `struct`?

Comment: In the OP's code, the ctors are private and use elaborated type specifiers. (dtors are private, too)

Comment: Would it still work if the template<typename T> was replaced with template<class T>?

Comment: @sgtHale Yes, `typename` and `class` are synonyms in this context.

Comment: Also I noticed that right after calling friend, you wrote "struct" Is there any difference as if it was just friend Manager?

Comment: @sgtHale It seems `template<typename T> friend Manager;` is not a valid *template-declaration*, even though just `friend my_type;` for some non-template class `my_type` is allowed. I'm not sure however why there is this difference.

Comment: @dyp I think I realized its because putting a "class" in front of it works like a forward declaration. I just tested it without and I received a "class does not name a type". Huh the more you know.